# Functional alternative?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, functional-programming, loops

As I continue my quest of learning functional programming, I've come
to wonder if there may be alternatives to my default "procedural" way
of thinking. To be more specific, I'm looking at a function I
wrote. Here is what it does:

```
Swap two elements of an unordered list of numbers, such that one of the elements  
 is now in the right place
Add the sum of the swapped values to an accumulated total   
Repeat until list is sorted
```

So, right now I'm using a standard loop* with an accum variable to do
the above. It works fine and all, and there's certainly nothing wrong
with iteration in real life, but as the point of this exercise is to
expand my way of thinking, I'm curious if there is a more functional
approach to the above algorithm.

Thanks!

*(Actually recursion, but whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From [EigenClass](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/fp-ocaml-koans):
>
> > The venerable master Leroy was walking with his student. Wishing to start a discussion with his master, the apprentice said "Master, I've heard that all loops must be replaced with tail-recursive functions. Is that true?" Leroy looked commiseratively at his student and replied "Foolish pupil, many tail-recursive functions are merely inefficient loops."
> >
> > The student spent the next few weeks replacing tail-recursive functions with explicit loops. He finally showed his code to master Leroy, seeking his approval. Leroy hit him with a stick. "When will you learn? Explicit loops are a poor man's tail-recursive functions." At that moment, the student became enlightened.

*Edit: Referring to Xavier Leroy, primary developer of OCaml*

Since I can't *see* your function to understand how functional* it is, I don't know. But it seems like what you are doing is correct. My main suggestion would be looking at data structures that lend themselves well to functional programming --but you are using lists, so that's out, although, lists aren't the best data structure in this case. As well as the algorithm. If you are pigeon holed into using the insertion sort, then you might not be able to use merge sort or other more efficient methods.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment ;)  I'm aware the algorithm is a bit silly; its purpose isn't so much to sort the list as to determine the "cost" of doing so (with cost defined as the minimum sum of the swaps required).

Comment: I've heard this in the context of objects vs. closures, but never loops vs tail calls. This stuff is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is basically a functional programming mechanism.  I guess you could replace your swap function with a function that took in a list and returned a list or something similarly silly, but that would be a bad idea unless written in a language which was actually functional.

Try implementing mergesort in Oz, SML, Prolog, or Lisp.  E.g. something like this pseudocode for merge:

```
Merge(A,[])=A
Merge(H|T,H2|T2)=iif(H<H2,H|Merge(T,H2|T2),H2|Merge(H|T,T2)
```

Comment: I am actually using Clojure, which is functional with immutable data structures, so my swap function does take a list and return one. Like I say, my question was mostly academic, to see if I was missing some neat call to reduce or map or something.